# Plugin for JetBrains IDEs that explains syntax and language constructs

Tags: go, ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

I'm looking for a plugin for the JetBrains suite of IDEs that explains language syntax and constructs. For example in golang:

```golang
grades := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I'd like to be able to highlight everything to the right of the `:=` and get a context action that says something like: *"creates an array of length equal to the number of elements in the braces"*. Or, when highlighting the `...` have the plugin tell me that *"it is a placeholder for the length of the array and is replaced at compile time with an int that represents the number of elements in the braces"*.

Does such a plugin exist? For JetBrains tools or other IDE?

Or in this situation we have another instance of 3 dots:

```golang
w8 = append(w8, w7...)
```

The plugin would let me hover over those 3 dots and it would display the golang docs that explain that particular syntax construct.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/06/ai-assistant-in-jetbrains-ides/